# Surface area of a sphere over a disc

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area, applications, multiple-integral

What's the surface area of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ over the disc $(x-1/2)^2 + y^2 \le 1/4$ ?

I've tried something, but I don't think it's right, as it's not a "nice answer"

So here is what I've done:

Firstly I parameterized using $x = r \cos(t)$, $y= r \sin(t)$, $z=z$.

$$dS = \sqrt{1+(dz/dx)^2+(dz/dy)^2} dA$$

$$dz/dx=2x , dz/dy=2y $$

Which gives me $$ \sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} dA = \sqrt{1+4r^2} r dr dt$$

Integral then becomes:
S = $\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{1/2}\sqrt{1+4r^2} r dr dt$

Solving this gives me the result $=0,96$, however I don't think it's right

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format posts on this site.

Comment: I am sorry, last time it made changes by itself, will try to sort it out asap

Comment: I made some edits to get you started

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: You are integrating over the disk $x^2y^2\leq\frac14$ which is not the region specified in the problem

Answer (score 1):

The border of the region in polar coordinates is:
$$(r\cos\theta - 1/2)^2 + (r\sin\theta)^2 = 1/4,$$
$$r = \cos\theta,$$
with $\theta\in\cdots$ (**Draw the circle** to see the interval of variation of $\theta$).